# How to return multiple row using sys cursor?

Tags: plsql

I am trying return multiple records using sys cursor but it will display only one record at time.so any one help to me?

I am using this query

> open attr for select * from table_name

Comment: Did you mean `sys_refcursor`?

Comment: Do you want to 'return' rows or 'display' them? What tool/application/technology will you be using?

Comment: So you are able to retrieve a cursor from the database but your Java code (wild guess) is not iterating over the set? Is that it?

Comment: What language is this application written in? And it's `sys_refcursor`, not `sys cursor` or `sys_ref cursor`.

Comment: Is the problem with the cursor or in your .Net code?

Comment: [How to ask a question on Stack Overflow](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below way:

```
declare
   l_rcursor sys_refcursor;

   var1     all_users.username%type;
   var2     all_users.user_id%type;
   var3     all_users.created%type;

   begin
      open l_rcursor for select * from all_users;

      Loop
        fetch  l_rcursor
        into var1,var2,var3;
        exit WHEN l_rcursor%NOTFOUND; 
        dbms_output.put_line(var1 ||','||var2||','||var3);
        end loop;
end;
```

Comment: This will still only fetch records one at a time.

Comment: Query is not about fetching the records. its all about displaying it.

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense - what does it mean to display records, if not "one at a time"? All on top of each other on the same line?

Comment: You can post your piece of code and then we can evaluate on that. I Just provided solution for what the OP asked. I just resolved the issue.

Comment: Good for you :) I prefer to wait for the OP to answer some more questions asked in the comments above.